# Unlinking an image

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code in which I want to use unlink to delete the image from the folder "images/slider_images" but I don’t know how to use it. Here’s my code:

```
$directory = 'images/slider_images/';     
try {        
    // Styling for images    
    echo '<div id="myslides">';    
    foreach ( new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $item ) {            
        if ($item->isFile()) {
            $path = $directory . '/' . $item;    
            echo '<img src="' . $path . '"/>';    
        }
    }    
    echo '</div>';
}    
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'No images found for this slideshow.<br />';    
}
```

Comment: You can simply do unlink($path);

Comment: I don't see any refrence to deleting an image. But if you want to unlink something just do it. Do not yet see the problem: unlink($path)

Comment: Why don't you read the PHP Man page for `unlink()`?

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as doing `unlink($path);`

Place that in your loop, where you retrieve the images.

```
   foreach ( new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $item ) {            
        if ($item->isFile()) {
            $path = $directory . '/' . $item;    
           unlink($path); //deletes the images   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, let's do some `img` tags with references to images we just deleted! Fun with de codz! Makes no sense.

Comment: I think the OP is sensible enough to remove the image tags :)

Comment: Common sense would have precluded the question.